# Send generic JSON data to MVC2 Controller

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-2, parameters, controller

I have a javascript client that is going to send json-formatted data to a set of MVC2 controllers.  The client will format the json, and the controller will have no prior knowledge of how to interpret the json into any model.  So, I can't cast the Controller method parameter into a known model type, I just want to grab the generic json and pass it to a factory of some sort.

My ajax call:

```
function SendObjectAsJSONToServer(object,url,idForResponseHTML) {
    // Make a call to the server to process the object
    var jsonifiedObject = JSON.stringify(object);
    $.ajax({
        url: url // set by caller
            , dataType: 'json'
            , data: jsonifiedObject
            , type: 'GET'
            , error: function(data) { alert('error in sendObjectAsJSONToServer:' + data); }
            , success: function(data) {
                alert(data.message); // Note that data is already parsed into an object
            }
    });
}
```

My MVC Controller:

```
public ActionResult SaveForm(string obj)
{
    // Ok, try saving the object
    string rc = PassJSONToSomething(obj.ToString());
    string message = "{\"message\":\""+rc+"\",\"foo\":\"bar\"}";
    return new ContentResult { Content = message, ContentType = "application/json" };
}
```

The problem is that obj is always null.  Can anyone tell me how I should structure the ajax call and the controller parameter so that I get my json to the server?  I'm using MVC2.  This may appear to be a duplicate of some SO questions, but in my case I do not know the Model that the json maps to, so I can't use a specific model type in the controller parameter type.

Thanks very much.

Comment: What happens if you change your string parameter to an object type (i.e. `public ActionResult SaveForm(object obj)`)?

Comment: @Phil.Wheeler - thanks, tried your suggestion - obj is not null, but the object appears 'empty' - it has no properties or methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried something like that?

```
$.ajax({
        url: url // set by caller
            , dataType: 'json'
            , data: {obj :jsonifiedObject}
            , contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
            , type: 'GET'
            , error: function(data) { alert('error in sendObjectAsJSONToServer:' + data); }
            , success: function(data) {
                alert(data.message); // Note that data is already parsed into an object
            }
    });
```

Comment: Radio - great, that's got it working.  Thanks. (Works with object or string in the controller signature)